# Is it possible download a mp3 file when new RSS feed is provided?

Tags: rss, if-this-then-that

I want to download a mp3 file when a new podcast is provided from [here](http://feeds.feedburner.com/Ruby5).

I used [this IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/recipes/33015-recuperating-the-mp3-files-from-an-audioboo-rss-feed) receipt by changing feed URL. But I only get an HTML file in my Dropbox folder that links to the last episode from the RSS.

Is there a way to save the mp3 file when new a feed is published with IFTTT?

Comment: The reason the recipe works for the original feed is because the MP3 filename is the same as the URL for the podcast with an `.mp3` appended to it. Unless the feed you're trying to do this with does the same thing you're not going to be able to do what you want.

Comment: As @AlE. notes, none of the feed data you can choose has the MP3 file in this case. The tag that does is the "enclosure" URL, which ifttt does not have on its dropdown menu. You could write a custom feed to "wrap" this feed and/or a webpage that redirects based on the feed URL, but both would require going above and beyond what ifttt does by itself.

Comment: The IFTTT receipt is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to do that, and ended up using [Zapier](https://zapier.com) to get the `.mp3` file link, and then send it to IFTTT via webhook to continue from there.

For that, you'll need to add from the Zap you're creating the values <sup>[1]</sup> you want to pass to the webhook (up to three).

### General steps:

#### IFTTT

1. Create an applet from the [webhooks trigger](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks).
2. Use one of the webhook values to continue your applet and trigger your action.

#### Zapier

1. Create a Zap with the RSS trigger
2. Select `New Item in Feed`
3. Select the `Webhooks` action with the POST method
4. In the `Edit Template`, select the field containing your `.mp3` link and set it to one of data the fields, with a name matching the one you chose in the IFTTT recipe (i.e `value1`/`value2`/`value3`).